# how to do not to go directly index.ctp when only cakephp/Controller/ instant of cakephp/Controller/index.ctp

Tags: cakephp

Controller Name : SaleController.php
action name     : index.ctp
 When I write localhost/cakephp/Sale/index is written in address bar,
index page of SaleController is shown.
 When I write localhost/cakephp/Sale/  is written in address bar,
index page of SaleController is shown.
Now,problem is **I don't want to go index file** **when localhost/cakephp/Sale/ is written.**
My cakephp version is 2.5.7.
If know ways,help me plz.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of solutions :

1. Select view in the controller
   in your SaleController.php

   function index(){
         $this->view="nameview.ctp";
   }
2. Routes :

   Router::connect(
       'Sale/',
       array('controller' => 'Sale' , 'action'=>'youraction' ),
       array('option' => 'matchingRegex')
   );
3. Select an other action in index

   function index(){
         $this->actionName();
   }

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But this means that is to change index.ctp name to other???1,2,3 all is required to do??

Comment: When 2.Routes:... is used,index is shown in address bar .But, when cakephp/Sale/ is written in addressbar,go to index.ctp.I also don't go to index.ctp this time.If have any ways , please help me!!

Comment: I had try.All of ways is not show index.ctp file name in address bar.I want to do is don't go to index.ctp when action name is not written in addressbar.If you have a ways help me.

Comment: Router::connect( 'Sale/', array('controller' => 'Sale' , 'action'=>'youraction' )); this works for me

Comment: I think it is a way not to show index.ctp file name 'index' in address bar.Now my problem is not to work index file when only controller name is written and index action name is not.

Comment: the thing is : when you go yoururl/Sale it show the action that you want , not index ? isnt it ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your controller name should be SalesController (plural s).

Second, action is a method within controller not a file (here index mehod).

Third, index.ctp is a view file.

Fourth, you can change view in action method with render function (e.g. $this->render('other.ctp'); )

Fifth you can have custom URLs with routes.

And last but not least! you've not grabbed a good understanding of the framework, It's better to restudy the documentation.